# Using session to Authenticate in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, php-5.3

i have two php applications in my local wamp server. both applications use the same mechanism to check the authentication by storing the login in sessions. my issue is if i login successfully in one application, the other app login automatically if i open in the same browser. both application login validation use the same php code(i copied from one app to the other).

my concern is how two application share the same session in wamp server? what i'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: the question needs clarification.  is that login on one application means you ARE logged in on the other application (and don't want to be) or that you WANT to be logged in on the other application but aren't?

Comment: @Grexis yes the apps are in same domain. my local wamp server so they go as. app1 is http://localhost/App1  and the other as  http://localhost/App2

Comment: @msgmash.com it's loged in on the other app (app2) which i dont wannt to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applications are probably running on the same domain, e.g. `http://localhost/app1` and `http://localhost/app2`. By default, PHP's session cookie is valid for the entire domain, so naturally, both applications share the session cookie. Here's what you can do:

- Use different session cookie names for either application (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php for how to do this)
- Run the applications on different domains (or subdomains); you can simulate this locally by adding fake domains to your hosts file, and running both applications on different Apache VHosts (or even on the same VHost, but then both applications will be available on both pseudo-domains)
- Limit the path on which the session cookie is valid (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php for details).

Answer (score 1):

Sessions use cookies (by default called `PHPSESSID`) to store the session key in the browser.

Since both your apps are in the same `localhost` domain, your browser is sending the same session id to both apps.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, this is caused by both applications being served by the `localhost` domain (and probably the same cookie name).  Since the applications have the same authentication backend, it makes sense that they would behave the same way.

While this probably would not be an issue in a production environment on isolated domains, consider adding a unique authentication token to each application that is verified before considering a user as logged in.

Another temporary local solution would be to use your hosts file to simulate separate domains in your development environment.

Comment: Perhaps when your app loads, you set a constant to a unique string, such as md5("I wear my dad's dirty socks");  When a user successfully logs in, add that string to an auth cookie.  When checking if a user is logged in, compare the string in your application to the string in the cookie to make sure it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Session key is stored in browser's cookies. Browser stores cookies for given domain. So I think both of your applications running at the same domain (localhost?). If so, you have to separate them to have it worked.

Also you can store separate session files in different places by using [session_save_path() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) in one of your applications